# Defining multiple optional parameters on a route

Tags: php, routes

Currently I use AltoRouter in my project, and I need a route that can match different optional parameters with **random order**. I've rewritten AltoRouter class to use XML + added feature for reusing parameters like:

```
<parameter name="page" match="[i:page]"/>

<route match="/blog" ...>
    <use param="page"/>
</route>
```

This will match both `/blog` and `/blog/2`.

Now I need a route like `/blog/[i:page]/[desc|asc:order]/[new|popular:sort]`
that can match URIs like `/blog/2/new` or `/blog/desc/2`, or just `/blog/2 , /blog/new`.

Is it possible to define a single route for such URIs (even using different router like Symfony) ? If no , how should one set multiple rules to match such URIs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution: all the optional parameters should be passed to the Controller's action. Such route can be defined with AltoRouter like this : `/blog/[**:params]`. This route will match /blog/ and the rest of the URL as *$params*. E.g. URL is /blog/2/desc/new, Controller's action will get '2/desc/new' as $params, those can be parsed with explode('/', $params) and processed as needed

Comment: Ensure that the function/controller looks like function(...$arg){.  }, Then in the route use /blog/[*:desc]/[*:/new], $arg = array('desc'=>value2, 'new'=> value2)

Comment: @Ncoder this is some next level necro-posting right there :D